# Django: How to get user id on forms.py?

Tags: django, django-forms

I would like to get the current logged in user id in my forms.py. I want to get the id of logged in user.
I am trying to query like this :

```
class ProcessForm(forms.ModelForm):
 
    company_objective = CompanyObjectives.objects.get(user_rel_objectives=request.user.id)
```

I get an error NameError: name 'request' is not defined. This makes sense but I have no idea how to get the id here. Plz, advise.

Comment: You need to use a Django `Field` before you start filtering choices. Please refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/

Comment: You should pass the request to your form. You also need to use a django field. take a look at django docs for modelforms.

Comment: What dose it mean to use a djnago field , sorry for noob question

Answer (score 0):

I did this :
in the view i have this:

> `user = request.user.id form = ProcessForm(user=request.user)`

and in the form i have this :

```
> def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
>         user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
>         super(ProcessForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
>         company_objective = CompanyObjectives.objects.get(user_rel_objectives=user.id)
>         print (company_objective.cost_reduction)
```

Comment: The rest of the form code would be really helpful

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this...

**views.py**

```py
context['form'] = ProcessForm(user=request.user.id)
```

**forms.py**

```py
class ProcessForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(ProcessForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['company_objective'] = CompanyObjectives.objects.get(user_rel_objectives=user)
```